# SQL Azure Database Copy status

Tags: azure-sql-database, azureportal

Copying a database in the Azure Portal is never ending.

Usually, when I copy a 250GB database, it completes in just under an hour.

Today, when I copy, it never seems to finish, it has been over two to three hours now.

[image: copy database progress]

And in the server activity logs, the last entry just says an update occured

[image]

Any idea on how to see more progress, percent complete, or any other way to see what might be locking it?  Nothing of use can be seen in the activty log json.

Comment: Okay, it just finally finished.  I should change question now to read, how to find out information about its progress.

Comment: I had the same issue - I think it's maybe because I downgraded the DTU's in the way through (S0) but not sure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use <kbd>[SYS.DM_OPERATION_STATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-operation-status-azure-sql-database)</kbd> to track many operations including `copy` in SQLAZURE..

Documentation states

> To use this view, you must be connected to the master database. Use the sys.dm_operation_status view in the master database of the SQL Database server to track the status of the following operations performed on a SQL Database:

Below are the operattions that can be tracked

- Create database
- Copy database. Database Copy creates a record in this view on both the source and target servers.
- Alter database
- Change the performance level of a service tier
- Change the service tier of a database, such as changing from Basic to Standard.
- Setting up a Geo-Replication relationship
- Terminating a Geo-Replication relationship
- Restore database
- Delete database

You can also try <kbd>sys.dm_database_copies</kbd> in master database for info about copy status ..This has `percent_complete` field  and below is what documentation has to say about this

> The percentage of bytes that have been copied. Values range from 0 to 100. SQL Database may automatically recover from some errors, such as failover, and restart the database copy. In this case, percent_complete would restart from 0.

**Note:**
This view has info only during the duration of copy operation..

Comment: Thanks, that's really handy to know